# Laravel Manual Auth Doesn't Stay Logged

Tags: laravel, authentication, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have an issue with authentication in `Laravel 5.7`

For example purposes, I have setup a fresh `Laravel 5.7` install with `Users` seed in the database

in the `web.php` file :

```
 Route::get('/', function () {
    if (!auth()->check()) {
        dump('Not Logged');
        auth()->login(\App\User::first(), true);
        dump(auth()->user()->toArray());
    } else {
        dump('Logged');
    }
```

[image]

What I expect is to have a `Not logged` the first time I visit the page, then a Logged each time I refresh the page.

But every time I have a `Not logged` response.

Does anyone know how to keep a user logged in manually?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't advise building an authentication on the web.php route file, you should try to split up the code in an organized way.
 Beware of `!auth()->check()`, because you're not exactly evaluating if it's false, you are validating the inversion of a bool. Meaning, if it's true, it's going to check if it's false.

Do you have a record in your User table?

Where are you storing your session, in a file or database?

Attempt `Auth::login(\App\User::first(), true);` and print out if the user is indeed logged with `dd(Auth::user())`

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: Yeah I know it's just an exemple build from a fresh laravel installation, that's why I just put it on the web file :)

I have some record in the User table (if I dump the `auth()->user()`right after the login, it works fine)

I am logged for the rest of the request, but don't stay logged for the next one

Comment: print the Auth::user() to confirm that your user is indeed logged

Comment: Auth component is working as expect, you can check if it's logged by creating a different route (Route::get(/test)) and print there the auth->user(). Also, just simplify the if statement, if (auth->check()) its logged, otherwise dump